# Why does @sys.any sometimes take entire input successfully as action and other times doesn't in dialogflow?

Tags: chatbot, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I need to capture the entire statement that user says into a variable and am using @sys.any for it. Why does it need to learn, can't it blindly just take everything into the variable specified for it in actions and parameters? Here's my dashboard for action and parameters:

[image]

To test I printed the question itself and here's the test window:
[image]

Comment: Can you update your question to give examples of when it works as you expect and when it doesn't? When it doesn't, what does it get? Do you actually just want to handle the scenario, or are you also trying to understand what is happening and why?

Comment: For example:
How to get EIN number? is correctly parsed and if I ask the same question it says the prompts message meaning it didn't the question. I want to handle the scenario of getting the entire question asked by the user.

Comment: Please update your question to give examples, show screen shots of specific Intents, and other things. It is really difficult to answer a very broad question like this.

Comment: I'm really not sure why you're using Dialogflow like this. Routing through Dialogflow, you can take full advantage of its machine learning to process your questions. There are ways to get the full raw text of the user, although I'm not sure what your training phrases look like